# VBA Datelastmodified of a file which path is listed in column

Tags: vba, excel

i have a column :

```
            A 
P:\Desktop\folderdestination\test.txt
P:\Desktop\folderdestination\test2.txt
```

and i want to know the date last modified  of the files in the column . Can you help me please ?

```
        Set workboo = Workbooks.Open("P:\Desktop\Column.xlsx")
        Set worksh = workboo.Worksheets("date_last_modified")
        Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
        Dim rngCell As Range
        Dim rngFiles As Range
        dim destinationfolder as string
dim dateLast as date
        destinationfolder="P:\Desktop\folder"
        lastcolumn = Cells(1, Cells.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
             For icol = 1 To lastcolumn Step 2
             lastLigne = Cells(Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Row
              For Each rngCell In rngFiles.Cells
              strFile = Right(rngCell.Value, Len(rngCell.Value) - InStrRev(rngCell.Value, "\"))
        'without extension    
        Filename = Left(strFile, (InStr(strFile, ".") - 1))
        filepath = worksh.Cells(rngCell).Value
dateLast=Filedatetime(rngCell.Value)
    If Dir(destinationFolder & dateLast & strFile, 16) = "" Then
        FSO.CopyFile rngCell.Value, destinationFolder & dateLast & strFile
       End If
```

Comment: You can simply use `FileDateTime(path to file)` rather than FSO.

Comment: @Rory thanks for your reply , i edited the code but still it doesn't work if i put datelast to name it .

Comment: If i remove dateLast , it copy the files with the name , but there is a problem once i put the date , can you help me with that ?

Comment: You need to format it as you were previously - eg: `dateLast = Format$(Filedatetime(rngCell.Value), "dd-mm-yy")`

Comment: You can't just use a date as it comes; there are `/` characters in it which will cause an error when saving to a file path.  Maybe try `datelast=Replace(Filedatetime(rngCell.Value), "/", "")` which would crop out the `/`

Comment: @Rory indeed , i edited and put your code but still not working ..

Comment: Not in what you posted. What **exactly** does "still not working" mean? What happens?

Comment: Thanks , it works !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `FSO.DateLastModified` as `DateLastModified` is a propery of a `File` object rather than the `FileSystemObject` itself.

You can find the information by setting an FSO reference to the file you want like this:

`Set oFile = FSO.GetFile("pathToFileHere")`

and then you can access the file properties with:

`oFile.DateLastModified`

..or indeed any one of a bunch of other properties (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ft05taf(v=vs.84).aspx) for further information about what's available.

If you want to use it in a timestamp, I generate them like this:

```
timestamp = Year(Now) & Right("00" & Month(Now),2) & Right("00" & Day(Now), 2) & "_" & Right("00" & Hour(Now), 2) & Right("00" & Minute(Now),2) & Right("00" & Second(Now),2)
```

This gives you a timestamp string in the format `yyyymmdd_hhmmss` which you can insert based on the current date.

Comment: thanks for you reply , i edited my code , but FileDateTime don't work .

Comment: If you want to use it in a file name, I'll add into the answer the method I use to generate a timestamp on files I create